# how to store value from two different fields like Date field, dropdown and accordingly update in the text field

Tags: reactjs, events, next.js, react-hooks

Requirement: the value in the text field say 'fieldA' need to be updated based on the selection of date field 'fieldB' and dropdown field of months say 'fieldC'. example: if date 01/01/2023 is selected and 2Months from dropdown selected then in the textfield 'fieldA' it should update as 01/03/2023. i.e it should add months to the existing date. if date field changes or month field changes the same should be updated to the text filed 'fieldA'.

im new to the react and nextjs and stuck to proceed further.

i tried to store value in useState but it didnt work for me, as event changes as and when i select value from other field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` and `useEffect` hooks. `useState` is for updating the state and `useEffect` is to trigger an action based on specified state variable values.

```
// declare state of all three fields with useState
const [fieldAVal, setFieldAVal] = useState(</*initia date Value*/>);
const [fieldBVal, setFieldBVal] = useState(</*initia date Value*/>);
const [fieldCVal, setFieldCVal] = useState(</*initia month Value*/>);

// update fieldAVal according to the values of fields B and C, so add them as dependency list of useEffect
useEffect(()=>{
   // update fieldAVal
   setFieldAVal(<field B's date + field C's duration>);
}, [fieldBVal, fieldCVal]);
```